# Keep trying to fix AttributeError, but can't figure it out

Tags: python, selenium, get

[image]

For some reason, it's telling me that selenium is not being used, and it's giving me an error on my `driver.get`, wondering what I'm doing wrong.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: No image of code please. [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `driver` is a string, and it should be

```py
# remove the quotation marks
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
```